# angularjs - controller inheritance calling parent

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a parent controller inside the first module and a "child" controller inside the  second module. The second module has a dependancy to the first. I want my "child" controller to inherit the "parent" controller. But the problem is how to call the "parent" controller method.

For example:

```
 SecondModule.controller("childBrowseCtrl", function($scope, $injector, $controller){
        $injector.invoke(ParentBrowseCtrl, this, {$scope:$scope});

        //this overrides the onedit function from parent
        $scope.onEdit = function(){
            console.log("from edit console");

            //how do i make this work?
            ParentBrowseCtrl.$scope.onEdit();
        };

});
```

The html structure:

```
 <html>
   <head></head>

   <body>
      <div ng-view></div>
   </body>

   <script src="coreapp.js"></script>
   <script src="mainapp.js"></script>

   <script>
     angular.bootstrap(document,["MainApp"]);
   </script>

   </html>
```

Comment: How are you setting up the html structure?

Comment: edited my question to include html structure

Comment: Ok this doesnt show any controllers being nested. Are you nesting them with routing?

Comment: Nope, the only thing thats close to inheritance is that i invoke the parent controller inside the child.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This may work:

```js
var parentOnEdit = $scope.onEdit;

$scope.onEdit = function() {
    parentOnEdit();
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Controllers setup inheritence through the prototype chain so if your controller nesting structure in the html is correct then the child controllers will inherit prototypically.

You can check this if you

```
console.log($scope);
```

in the children controllers to see if they properly inherited from the parent.

Comment: $scope.$parent has the rootScope, there is no nesting of controllers in the html.

Comment: Controller do not inherit, but their $scope property does.

Comment: if i override the $scope.onEdit function, then the implementation of the parent onEdit is gone, that's whats bugging me.

Comment: @zPrima Then the structure is setup correctly - this is how prototypical inheritance works.

Comment: Somehow i did not try to save the onEdit function before overriding it :) @sp00m answer did just that.

Comment: OK.. I see the idea but why do you need 2 onEdit functions? shouldn't the child inherit from the parent? remove the $scope.onEdit from the child controller...

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
$scope.$parent.onEdit();
```

Great article about scopes: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes

Comment: maybe `onEdit()` in more than one step-parent scope? `$scope.$parent.$parent` or more... but it is bad practice. If so, you need to rethink structure of this.

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me

```
// in parent
$scope.parentFnCall = $scope.functionName;

// in child
$scope.parentFnCall()
```